# Locally finite closed family makes a function continious

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a closed, locally finite family such that $X = \cup_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha$, $f:X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f|_{A_\alpha}$ is continous for every $\alpha \in A$. Show that $f$ is continous.

I've tried to use the (stick?) lemma (I don't know how it's called in english what in spanish is "El lema del pegado"). I tried taking a closed subset $H \subset Y$ and to prove that $f^{-1}(H) \subset X$ is closed.

But after $f^{-1}(H) = \cup_{\alpha \in A} (f|_{A_\alpha})^{-1}(H) =: F$ I couldn't do much more. I said that is this is not closed, then $X \setminus F$ is not open, then there exists $x \in X \setminus F$ such that for every open set $U \in X$ such that $x \in U$, $U \cap F \neq \varnothing$. I'm not sure if this leads to something or if I should go in other direction

Thanks

Comment: If $X = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} A_\alpha$ then  $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ can not be locally finite  because every open neighborhood $U$ of any $x\in X$ is contained in $X$, hence intersects every $A_{\alpha}$ or am I misreading the question? Do you mean the union?

Comment: I miswrote. Now is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For brevity let $F=\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}.$

Any $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f$ is locally continuous, that is, iff for every $x\in X$ there is an open $U\subset X$ with $x\in U,$ such that $f|_U$ is continuous.

Take any $x\in X$ and let $U$ be open in $X$ with $x\in U$ and such that the set $B=\{b\in F: b\cap U\ne \emptyset\}$ is finite, which is possible because $F$ is locally finite. Since $\cup F=X,$ we have $$U=\cup \{b\cap U: b\in F\}=\cup \{b\cap U:b\in B\}.$$

Let $C$ be any closed subset of $Y.$ From the line above, we have $$(f|_U)^{-1}C= \cup \{U\cap ((f|_b)^{-1}C):b\in B\}.$$ Now each $f|_b$ is continuous so $(f|_b)^{-1}C$ is closed in $b,$

while $b$ is closed in $X,$

so $(f|_b)^{-1}C$ is closed in $X,$

so $U\cap ((f|_b)^{-1}C)$ is closed in $U,$

and $B$ is finite so $(f|_U)^{-1}C=\cup \{U\cap ((f|b)^{-1}C): b\in B\}$ is closed in $U.$

So $f|_U$ is continuous.

So $f$ is locally continuous, hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: With $D=(f|_b)^{-1}C$ and with the closure bar denoting closure in $X,$ we have $D=\bar D$... So $U\cap D \subset Cl_U(U\cap D)=$ $U\cap \overline {U\cap D}\subset$ $ U\cap \bar D=$ $U\cap D$... So $U\cap D$ $ is$ closed in $U.$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C$ is closed in $Y$. Then, $\left(f|_{A_i}\right)^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $A_i$ for each $i$. And since $A_i$ is closed in $X$, it follows that $\left(f|_{A_i}\right)^{-1}(C)\cap A_i$ is closed in $X.$ If we can show that $\bigcup_i\left(f|_{A_i}\right)^{-1}(C)\cap A_i$ is closed in $X$, we are done, because $f^{-1}(C)=\bigcup_i\left(f|_{A_i}\right)^{-1}(C)\cap A_i$.

But this follows at once because  $\{\left(f|_{A_i}\right)^{-1}(C)\cap A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a locally finite collection of closed sets to which we may apply the following theorem: the union of a locally finite collection of closed subsets of a topological space is itself closed. Here is the proof:

Let $\mathscr A$ be a locally finite collection of closed subsets of $X$, and consider $S:=\bigcup \mathscr A$. Let $x\in X\setminus S$. By local finiteness there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ that meets only finitely many members of $\mathscr A$, say $A_1,\cdots ,A_n$. So $U\setminus S=U\setminus \bigcup^n_{i=1}A_i$ is open and contains $x$. That is, for each $x$ in the complement of $S$, there is an open set containing $x$ that does not meet $S$. Therefore, $X\setminus S$ is open, and so $S$ is closed, as desired.

Comment: Not a criticism of your A, but I have posted an A that does not use the theorem that the union of a locally finite closed family is closed. I'd appreciate your thoughts about its correctness.

Comment: Your proof is fine. Happy to upvote it.

Comment: I gave you a +1 (last night) too.